# Need help in using authenticate function in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I keep getting wrong number of arguments (2 for 1). 
What is wrong here? 
Previously it was giving be authenticate not defined in class error and now i have this error.

def create
      user = Customer.where(:email => params[:email]).first

```
  if(user && user.authenticate(params[:email], params[:password]))
     session[:user_id] = Customer.id
     redirect_to root_path, :notice => "Logged in successfully"
  else
     flash.now[:alert] = "Invalid login/password combination"
     render :action => 'new'
 end
```

end

And my Customer class

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base

 devise :database_authenticatable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

 has_one :preference
 has_secure_password

end
```

Comment: are you using `devise`? or  `authenticate`method is defined by you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not first find user by email. Just call method like below.

```
def create
user = User.authenticate(params[:email], params[:password])
if user
  session[:user_id] = user.id
  redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Logged in!"
else
  flash.now.alert = "Invalid email or password"
  render "new"
end
end
```

Comment: I also made it work through this                                             -->if(user && user.valid_password?(params[:password]))